# Create View multiple tables and different column names

Tags: sql, view, sql-server-2014

I have 2 tables in my database:

**DetectorStatus**

```
DetectorStatusID    DetectorID    DateTime    DetectorModeID    Status
      1                471          time            2            0.7
```

**StationStatus**

```
StationStatusID    DetectorID    DateTime    StationModeID    Status
      1                1541        time            2           0.74
```

I want to create a view that looks like this:

```
StationStatusID    DetectorStatusID    DetectorID    DateTime    StationModeID    DetectorModeID    Status
      NULL                 1               471         time          NULL                2            0.7
      1                    NULL            1541        time          2                   NULL         0.74
```

Now, when i create the view like this:

```
CREATE view statusoverview AS
    SELECT * FROM [GMS_MAN].[dbo].[DetectorStatus]
    UNION ALL
    SELECT * FROM [GMS_MAN].[dbo].[StationStatus]
```

I get all the results inside 1 table. However *StationModeID* is inside *DetectorModeID* etc.

How do i create a view that looks like the given example?

Comment: Select null columns as well.

Comment: When i change the *SELECT * FROM* and add the columns + NULLS, It says: **No column was specified for column 1 of viewname**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to ensure that both result sets contain all of the columns you want:

```
CREATE view statusoverview AS
SELECT null as StationStatusID,
       DetectorStatusID,
       DetectorID,
       DateTime,
       null as StationModeID,
       DetectorModeID,
       Status
FROM [GMS_MAN].[dbo].[DetectorStatus]
UNION ALL
SELECT StationStatusID,
       null,
       DetectorID,
       DateTime,
       StationModeID,
       null,
       Status
FROM [GMS_MAN].[dbo].[StationStatus]
```

Note that the column names are taken from the first query, so it needs to name all of the columns. The second can omit naming the columns it's supplying `null`s for.

Comment: Thank you! It's giving me the exact result that i want. Also very clear and understandable written. Can accept answer in 5 minutes.

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT null as StationStatusID,DetectorStatusID,DetectorID,DateTime,null StationModeID,DetectorModeID,Status FROM [GMS_MAN].[dbo].[DetectorStatus]
    UNION ALL
    SELECT StationStatusID, null, DetectorID,DateTime,StationModeID, null ,Status FROM [GMS_MAN].[dbo].[StationStatus]
```

I might have do some column misspellings, but it iwll be something like that

Answer (score 0):

Well, you won't use SELECT *, you will specify which columns you want to have in your table:

```
CREATE view statusoverview AS
SELECT detector.*, station.StationStatusID, station.StationMode,station.Status 
FROM DetectorStatus detector
LEFT JOIN StationStatus station ON station.DetectorID=detector.DetectorID.
```

Whatever you choose, I think you shouldn't "SELECT *, but specify what you need"